# I can't figure out why I keep seeing "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: val"

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the images inside my `getImageForLogo.js` to load through a loop.

That file looks like so:

```
const images = {
  logo1: require('../assets/logo1.jpeg'),
  logo2: require('../assets/logo2.png'),
  'logo with space': require('../assets/logo-with-space.jpeg'),
};

export default logos => images[logos];
```

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

import getImageForLogo from './utils/getImageForLogo';
import Avatar from './components/Avatar';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      logos: 'logo1'
    };
  }

  render () {
    const {
      logos
    } = this.state;
    const form = { 'Logo1': 'assets/logo.jpg', 'Logo2': 'assets/logo2.jpg', 'Logo3': 'assets/logo3.jpg' };

    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.timerlist}>
          Object.values(form).map((key, val) => (
            <Avatar
              initials="KC"
              size={75}
              key={val}
              source={key}
              backgroundColor={'blue'}
              onPressLinkImage={() => {
                console.log('Pressed!');
              }}
            />
          ));
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I created the `const form` just to try and see if the loop works. I'm trying to cycle by using:

```
Object.values(form).map((key, val) => (
  <Avatar
    initials="KC"
    size={75}
    key={val}
    source={key}
    backgroundColor={'blue'}
    onPressLinkImage={() => {
      console.log('Pressed!');
    }}
  />
));
```

however, when I run this, the app crashes and says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: val`. I can't figure out why this happens because if I run this code on the Chrome terminal, it works.

**EDIT:**

Here's `Avatar.js`:

```
import {
  ColorPropType,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import getImageForLogo from '../utils/getImageForLogo';

export default function Avatar({
  size,
  backgroundColor,
  initials,
  source,
  onPressLinkImage,
}) {
  const style = {
    width: size,
    height: size,
    borderRadius: size / 2,
    backgroundColor,
  };

  const image = getImageForLogo(source)

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressLinkImage}>
        <Image source={image} style={styles.image} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

  );
}

Avatar.propTypes = {
  initials: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  source: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  backgroundColor: ColorPropType.isRequired,
  onPressLinkImage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code of `Avatar` component?

Comment: Alternatively, replace `Avatar` component with `Text` component, and see if it can print out the element of `form`, in that way we can tell if problem is in `App.js` or in `Avatar.js` right?

Comment: in your code. the key param contains the value of form while the val param contains the index. i think you should swap that. show avatar component to clarify

Comment: I added Avatar.js @Isaac

Comment: Yeah, I did notice, I'll change that as well @Mervzs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the App.js appears to be missing some `{ }` around your `Object.values`.

So instead of putting inside your `ScrollView`

```
Object.values(form).map((key, val) => (
    <Avatar
      initials="KC"
      size={75}
      key={val}
      source={key}
      backgroundColor={'blue'}
      onPressLinkImage={() => {
        console.log('Pressed!');
      }}
    />
  )
);
```

you should put

```
{Object.values(form).map((key, val) => (
    <Avatar
      initials="KC"
      size={75}
      key={val}
      source={key}
      backgroundColor={'blue'}
      onPressLinkImage={() => {
        console.log('Pressed!');
      }}
    />
  )
)}
```

notice that it is contained inside the `{ }`.

Here is it inside your `App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

import getImageForLogo from './utils/getImageForLogo';
import Avatar from './components/Avatar';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      logos: 'logo1'
    };
  }

  render () {
    const {
      logos
    } = this.state;
    const form = { 'Logo1': 'assets/logo.jpg', 'Logo2': 'assets/logo2.jpg', 'Logo3': 'assets/logo3.jpg' };

    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.timerlist}>
          {Object.values(form).map((key, val) => (
            <Avatar
              initials="KC"
              size={75}
              key={val}
              source={key}
              backgroundColor={'blue'}
              onPressLinkImage={() => {
                console.log('Pressed!');
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Also note your `Object.values(form).map((key, val)` will give the following keys and values

```
     key         | val
assets/logo.jpg  |  0
assets/logo1.jpg |  1
assets/logo2.jpg |  2
```

---

For readability of your code I would change your code to the following:

```
{Object.values(form).map((source, key) => (
    <Avatar
      initials="KC"
      size={75}
      key={key}
      source={source}
      backgroundColor={'blue'}
      onPressLinkImage={() => {
        console.log('Pressed!');
      }}
    />
  )
)}
```